# Getting text from the Resource file in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, localization, resource-file

i have an asp.net webpage, which contains a label, now i want to get the text property of the label from the localresource file, i have a `.resx` file under `App_LocalResources` folder, which contains Name as `UserNameLabel.Text` and Value as `User Name` now in my `aspx` file i am using `Label` control like this

`<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" resourcekey="UserNameLabel"></asp:Label>`

but i cannot get the text on the Label, can anyone tell me the correct way to add the Text Property from resource file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create appropriate structure inside web project. In this case I will be using Default.aspx:

[image]

Take notice I have placed Default.aspx.resx file inside App_LocalResources.

Next enter new item inside Default.aspx.resx like this:

[image]

The important thing is you need to set Text property (UserNameLabel.Text)

And finally here is aspx code:

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="UserNameLabel"></asp:Label>
```

I have used meta:resourcekey to link to appropriate resource key.